# Android:-Video player

Tags: android

I made a video player app that will pick a video at runtime to play. After picking a video it gives an error of Can't play video.[image: this is the error message]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
VideoView videoView;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    videoView= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(galleryIntent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select 
Video"),9);
}
    });}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==9 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri videoUri=data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoView.start();}}}
```

`

Comment: what is the video file type? is there any relevant error in the logcat?

Comment: Video file type is .mp4. No relevant error in logcat.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to add OnPreparedListener via calling this [setOnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)), and start playing from onPrepared callback.

2) Replace VideoView and MediaPlayer with [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). It is more stable than default player, also based on default android components, so it is lightweight.